# Associativity of plus on the reals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does the associativity of addition on the reals means that if there is an expression containing real numbers and plus symbols only, means there are no parenthesis required?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. But you need the commutativity of addition too.

Comment: An induction argument can then show that the statement without parentheses is well defined.

Comment: why need commutativity..?

Comment: Function composition is associative but not commutative, and no parentheses are required to understand $f\circ g\circ h$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel why do you need commutativity? Wouldn't that only be when you want to move numbers around so in an expression?

Comment: OK, I must have derped there.

Comment: Actually, leaving the parentheses out is just using the "default parentheses positions", like, $a+b+c+d$ automatically means $((a+b)+c)+d$. After all, $+$ remains a binary operation.

Answer (score 3):

That is correct.  Once you have associativity for three summands, four and more follow by induction as you can keep one pair grouped and use whatever proved it for three.  Usually associativity for three is an axiom.  You don't need commutativity as long as you keep them in order.

Answer (score 0):

Addition of reals is a binary operation.
Parentheses (Guides to how to get the intended from the expression) are not needed because associativity means once you have the order fixed all paths of computation yield the same outcome.

If you pretend addition does not commute, the order is crucial, and then make sure to always work adding leftie to rightie :)